# How to select all from an excel sheet where a column contains with specific strings

Tags: vb.net, database-connection

I have this

```
Select * from [Sheet1$]
```

i use in my vb code in connection with database engine to select all data from an excel sheet.
But this time i would want to select all where column L contains `PSM , VNM , TAMD or X00`.
Please how do i write the query.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the question targets only the SQL then you could do this:

```
"SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE L IN ('PSM', 'VNM', 'TAMD', 'X00')"
```

More help here:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp